# Schedule Presto query everyday and send the o/p as email

Tags: bash, presto

I am running few Presto queries daily using DBeaver and take the displayed o/p and send an email manually. I want to automate this task. The queries should run everyday at a particular time and I should receive the o/p as email. How can I achieve this. Can I do this using a Bash shell script.

Comment: We replied in Slack. https://prestosql.slack.com/archives/CP1MUNEUX/p1606474833470600

Comment: You can use ETL tool like: Apache-Airflow